# How to show nested array values in ejs template?

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
I am trying to pass the following json into an ejs template file.

   [my json][1]

 How can I loop through them all ?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWbL.png
```

this is my controller class.

```
module.exports.pi_olurlarEditGet = function (req, res) {
    olurlar.find(function (req, results) {
        console.log(results);

        res.render('PEditOlurlar', { Polurlar: results });
    });

}
```

In this everything is going perfect now problem is that, I am unable to show fetched  nested object data from mongodb to ejs template.
  I tried this but can not showed the nested object.

json.parse() operation also did not work.

```
ejs file :


    <% 
              for (var key in Polurlar) { %>

                <%if(Polurlar.hasOwnProperty(key)) { %>

                    <th><b>#</b></th>
                    <th><b><%=key+1%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].kesifArtisi%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].yenifiyat%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].geciciKabul%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].kesinKabul%></b></th>

                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].sureUzatimi%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].odenekDegisikligi%></b></th>


                    <th><b><a href="/login/kullanicisil/">duzenle</a></b></th>
                </tr>

       <%}%>
    <%}%>

this is only showed:

    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].kesifArtisi%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].yenifiyat%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].geciciKabul%></b></th>
                    <th><b><%=Polurlar[key].kesinKabul%></b></th>

please help me .. for your help thank you .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with nested object, my JSON was an array of object and inside it I had other array that contain multiple objects, I couldn't loop through it and display with EJS since the names were equal and the function you use, a for loop with key couldn't give the expected output.

To solve it, I gave up trying to use multiple objects and made a single array inside each object. Then I only needed to display every item inside this array, a For each to run the whole document and a for with this array length to display every element.

Unfortunately I couldn't understand completely your question, maybe a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) could help. I'm [sharing a project](https://github.com/pebueno/questionnaire-creator) with the situation I described, I hope it helps, variables name are in Portuguese but I'm using only Express and Ejs.